# Third highest salary in mysql without using max or min function

Tags: mysql

Someone please tell me how to get the third highest salary from the salary table using mysql **without using max or min function**, I have already done it using the max and min function and it is working fine but i want to do it without using these two functions, please help me

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Sort it, then take third row.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without using max or min?

Comment: Is this for an assignment? Hint: `LIMIT`

Comment: Everybody to the `LIMIT`. Penalties `OFFSET`.

Comment: Do we assume that everyone's salary is different?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a second bite at the apple for a bad question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176306/third-highest-salary-in-mysql-without-using-max-or-min-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a LIMIT and an OFFSET ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm47565134710112))

```
SELECT * FROM salaries ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 2,1;
                                         OFFSET --^ ^-- LIMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT` the salaries from the table, [`SORT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) them in descending order, use [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm47565134710112) to grab the 3rd result.

Comment: Why the -1? Kind of rude to down vote with no reason.

Comment: Indeed, I upvoted because you did **not** present a query but the necessary info to write one. Good work.